# error "Call to a member function count() on null" when using laravel orm

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to do the following query with the ORM of Laravel:

```
public function rate_already_existing(Request $request)
    {
        $requests = DB::table('requests')
            ->join('feedbacks', 'requests.id', '=', 'feedbacks.request_id')
            ->select('requests.id')
            ->where('requests.id', '=', $request->input('assistanceRequestId'))
            ->get();

        if(count($requests) > 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

The function should check if a request have already a feedback... in that case it returns true. 
The function above works, but I would like to do that function with the ORM to avoid too many rows and I tried the following:

```
public function rate_already_existing(Request $request)
{
    $request_match = Req::find($request->input('assistanceRequestId'))->feedback->count();

    if($request_match > 0) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately using the second function when the query have no rows the following error appears:

```
Call to a member function count() on null
```

Request model and feedback model have a one-to-one relationship.

Can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs when

```
Req::find($request->input('assistanceRequestId'))
```

is not able to find the row on the table. So it returns `null`. or when your relationship data return null use `if` condition to determine if data exists then try to use count method.

And since you are trying to get the count of the relationship directly why not use

```
 $request_match = Req::where('id', $request->input('assistanceRequestId'))->withCount('feedback')->first();
```

This [withCount](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) gives you the count of the relationship as 'feedback_count.

so you can use it like,

```
  if($request_match && $request_match->feedback_count > 0){
     return true
  }
```

But if you wanna only check if feedback exists and don't care about the data fetched since you are returning boolean data then try this,

```
$hasFeedback = Req::where('column_name', $request->input('assistanceRequestId'))->has('feedback')->exists();

return $hasFeedback;
```

This takes less resource and is faster than loading full data from the database and performing count check. To learn more about `has()` method and its importance for a scenario like  yours try to check out the larval doc's [Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the solution

```
public function rate_already_existing(Request $request)
{
   $request_match = Req::find($request->input('assistanceRequestId'))->feedback;

   return empty($request_match);

}
```

or

```
public function rate_already_existing(Request $request)
{
   $request_match = Req::with('feedback')->where('id', $request->input('assistanceRequestId'))->get();

   return empty($request_match);
}
```

You don't need the count number, so you can check with empty

Comment: When request_match has no rows still appears the error: Call to a member function get() on null.

Comment: Yes, you are using "find", you don't need to use get() or count()
   $request_match = Req::find($request->input('assistanceRequestId'))->feedback; 
or 
Req::with('feedback')
            ->where('id', $request->input('assistanceRequestId'))
            ->get();

Answer (score 0):

You can take leverage of [withCount()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models).

```
$request_match = Req::find($request->input('assistanceRequestId'))->withCount('feedback')->get();

if($request_match->feedback_count > 0) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: but this will still gives you `Call to a member function withCount() on null` error if find methods returns null. Since you are first trying to load the data and then trying to get the relationship count of the returned eloquent Model object.

Comment: It appears the following error: Property [feedback_count] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.

Comment: Or you can simply do `->has('feedback')->get()` and your condition would be `if($request_match) `

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function rate_already_existing(Request $request)
{
    $request_match = Req::findOrFail($request->input('assistanceRequestId'))->feedback()->count();

    if($request_match > 0) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

OR

```
public function rate_already_existing(Request $request)
{
    $request_match = Req::findOrFail($request->input('assistanceRequestId'))->feedback;

    if(!is_null($request_match)) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not think the other way around? Like:

```
public function rate_already_existing(Request $request)
    {
        $feedback = Feedback::select('request_id')->where('request_id', $request->input('assistanceRequestId'))->first();

        if($feedback != null) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

And if you want to return the request then return $feedback->request .... or something like that.